# Change the author of comments

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a list of words in a table. I have a VBA word macro that reads this table. When the macro identifies the words in the table, it adds comments or suggestions. For example: "don't use that word". Currently the author of those comments is defaulted to the name of whoever runs the macro. If user John Wayne runs the macro, each comment is displayed with the label "John Wayne" as the author. How can I change the author to "robot"?  I added the comment.author line but it doesn't work.

```
Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
   suggestion = Documents(DocName).Tables(1).Rows(RowCounter).Cells(CellWithSuggestion).range.Text
   ActiveDocument.Comment.Author = "robot"
   ActiveDocument.Comments.Add findRange, Text:=suggestion
   findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd    'to avoid getting into endless loop
Loop   'do while
```

Comment: From the docs it appears the author of a comment is a read-only property. I would guess Word uses Application.UserName to set this value - I think you could try to assign `Application.UserName = "robot"` before creating the comment (and then set it back to its original value afterwards)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I added the parameter Application.UserName = "robot", however the comments continue to be added with my name. This did not solve the question, please tell me if you have other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround to change the author of comments to "robot":

1. Add "_0" at the end of all comment's author name.
2. Process to add new comments.
3. Change comments to author = "robot". Comments with an author that ends in "_0" stay intact.

```
Dim brand As String
Dim Comment As Comment
brand = "robot"
If ActiveDocument.Comments.Count > 0 Then
   For Each Comment In ActiveDocument.Comments
       Comment.Author = Comment.Author & "_0"
   Next
End If
If ActiveDocument.Comments.Count > 0 Then
   For Each Comment In ActiveDocument.Comments
       If InStr(1, Comment.Author, "_0", 1) = 0 Then
          Comment.Author = brand
       End If
   Next
 End If
```

Comment: Not sure I understand how step 2 happens with this code, but happy you found a work-around! As written, the two outer conditions and foreach loop blocks could/should be combined, there's no apparent reason to have two separate blocks, and no apparent reason the 2nd block can possibly update any comment's author. Is something missing between the two blocks?

Comment: I still believe that you could use my `addComment` sub directly - if you pass a correct range for `rgComment` - as your code does nothing else than mine: setting the Author of a comment. What you could try is passing the document itself to to the sub as well - as that is the point where it fails on your side

Comment: @mathew guindon and Ike You are correct, there's a long process in between those two sections. Section 1 above happens at the start of the macro to identify pre-existing comments and adding the "_0" to the author's name. Then there's the long process that identifies words in the document and adds comments to enhance the document. These comments are automatically setup as authored by whoever is running the code. Section 2 takes the comments generated by the macro and changes the comments author to "robot". The author's with "_0" remain as they were before running the macro. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the author per created comment.

Use this sub for it

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Const SystemAuthorForComments As String = "robot"

Sub addComment(rgComment As Range, strMessage As String, _
    Optional ByVal strAuthor As String)

If LenB(strAuthor) = 0 Then strAuthor = SystemAuthorForComments 

Dim doc As Word.Document: Set doc = rgComment.Parent

Dim c As Word.Comment
Set c = doc.Comments.Add(rgComment, strMessage)
c.Author = strAuthor

End Sub
```

You would have to change your code snippet to:

```vb
Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
   suggestion = Documents(DocName).Tables(1).Rows(RowCounter).Cells(CellWithSuggestion).Range.Text
   
   addComment findrange, suggestion  '--> this is how you call the sub
   
   findrange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd    'to avoid getting into endless loop
Loop   'do while
```

Comment: I adapted the subroutines that you suggested to have a fixed suggestion only. However, I get error:

Comment: Sub Author()
Dim findRange As Word.range 
Dim suggestion As String
Const NewAuthor As String = "robot"
suggestion = "message"
addComment findRange, suggestion
findRange.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
End Sub  Sub addComment(rgComment As range, strMessage As String)
If LenB(strAuthor) = 0 Then strAuthor = NewAuthor
Dim doc As Word.Document
Set doc = rgComment '.Parent
Dim c As Word.Comment
Set c = doc.Comments.Add(rgComment, strMessage)
c.Author = strAuthor
End Sub

Comment: You could provide the default value for the optional parameter instead of checking the length of the provided value (Optional ByVal strAuthor As String="robot")... I'm not familiar with the Word object model but Comment.Author isn't documented?

Comment: First: you must not comment `.Parent`to retrieve the word.doc from the range. Second: with the code posted `findRange` is empty. I supposed that you set `findrange` before the `do while`-loop. @MathieuGuindon: you are right - it is not documented - but it works :-)

Comment: @Ike I commented .Parent because I keep getting error: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Comment: what is your word version?

Comment: @Ike Word version 2019

Comment: I checked on Word 2016: this should work. Can you check your `findrange` - it should be a range and not nothing.

Comment: @Ike, I found a work around. Thanks